# Can't get values from different fields in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a page with two section(forms), first is about number of how many new fields I want to create and second - where are the new fields. So my problem is that I can't get the information from second fields. Here is the code:

```
echo "<form action='create-table.php' method='post'>";
echo "How much fields you want?: <input type='numer' name='fieldsnum'><br>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='first'>";
echo "</form>";

$fieldsnum = $_POST["fieldsnum"];

echo "<form action='create-table.php' method='post'>";
echo "Table Name: <input type='text' name='table'><br><br>";
$table = $_POST["table"];
echo $table;

while ($a < $fieldsnum){
    echo "Table Field $a: <input type='text' name='$a'><br>";
    $a++;
}

echo "<input type='submit' name='second'>";
echo "</form>";

for($a = 0; $a<$fieldsnum; $a++){
     $info[$a] = $_POST[$a];
}
```

First loop work correctly, but the second has some problem and it can't get the data. I don't understand PHP and I am sorry if it has a lot of mistakes or bad practices.

Comment: Why on earth would you wanna create forms in php?

Comment: What you mean? I need it for database.

Comment: What I mean is you need to start from the basics.. It is bad practice to `echo` html in your php script. Also, there is no validation in your $_POST variables which will make the whole thing vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: It's about for close system. It will use in local area(private), no public. Which means port 80 will be closed from router. So I don't worry about SQL injection. It's not necessary to be some good code or fast. I just need to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong here:

First, you need to set `$a = 0;` before your `while` loop, otherwise the first iteration of

`while ($a < $fieldsnum){...}`

Will output:

```
<input type="text" name>
```

So you will get no data from that field.

Secondly, Your `for` loop fails because `$fieldsnum` is empty on the second submission.

Try this:

```
<?php

    $fieldsnum = $_POST["fieldsnum"]; 
    $table = $_POST["table"];

    if (isset($_POST["fieldsnum_keep"])) {

        $fieldsnum = $_POST["fieldsnum_keep"];

        for($a = 0; $a < $fieldsnum; $a++){
         $fieldName = $_POST["feild_$a"];
         echo "Field Name $a : $fieldName <br>";
        }

    }

?>
<form action='create-table.php' method='post'>
    How much fields you want?
    <input type='number' name='fieldsnum'><br>
    Table Name: 
    <input type='text' name='table'><br>

    <?php 
        echo $table . "<br>";
        $a = 0; 
        while ($a < $fieldsnum){ 
          echo "Field Name $a: <input type='text' name='feild_$a'><br>";
          echo "<input type='hidden' name='fieldsnum_keep' value='$fieldsnum'><br>";
          $a++;
        } 
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="second" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have kept the value of `$fieldsnum` by adding it to a hidden field and then using it later in the for loop.  I have also made it only one form, which will by submitted twice, instead of 2 forms.

Comment: This works for me, I am able to get all the data from the feilds.  If I enter 4 tables, it gives me for input fields for 4 field names and get all those field names in `$_POST` when I submit.  How are you using the data after submitting the form?

Comment: I just trying to get from here:

`for($a = 0; $a<$fieldsnum; $a++){

     $info[$a] = $_POST[$a];

     echo info[$a];

}` with echo.

Comment: It works and for me, but I can't get the data with loop..Some idea how  can I make it?

Comment: @ValeriRangelov I see what you mean, I have edited my answer above